# Is it possible to add the Chrome Task Manager to the Chrome Unity quicklist?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, quicklists

Is it possible to add the Chrome Task Manager to the Chrome Unity quicklist as an option?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can start it with task manager window opened. But if it's possible, it must be with the "--webui-task-manager" switch.

Open this file for editing:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Find the text below:

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=[your quicklist option groups]
```

Change it to:

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=[your quicklist option groups];TaskManager
```

Then add at the very bottom:

```
 [TaskManager Shortcut Group]
 Name=Task Manager
 Exec=google-chrome --webui-task-manager
 TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Save and close.